# How to access TwitterClient in OAuthWebSecurity for consumerKey and consumerSecret

Tags: twitter, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm successfully using ASP.Net MVC's OAuthWebSecurity to authenticate a Twitter user.  I'm using LINQ to Twitter to interact with Twitter's API to retrieve data about user and post tweets.  LINQ to Twitter requires the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret in order to interact with Twitter API.  You have to supply ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret when registering TwitterClient with OAuthWebSecurity.  How do I retrieve ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret from OAuthWebSecurity?

Answer (score 0):

OAuthWebSecurity is only for authentication. You need authorization to read the timeline and post tweets.
You should write your own authorization code to retrieve the consumerkey + secret.

Comment: I added consumerKey + consumerSecret to the extendedData dictionary for Twitter registration with OAuthWebSecurity.  It works, I can access the values now throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go on https://dev.twitter.com/apps a create your twitter app there. They will then give you the Consumer key and Consumer secret.